# Nativescript and Stripe Integration : Duplication of dependencies on Stripe in Podfile

Tags: angular, nativescript, stripe-payments

I'm having issues with the integration of Stripe in my Angular/Nativescript app.
Since I've added Stripe to the app, the following error comes when I launch the 'tns run ios' command:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Stripe":
  In Podfile:
    Stripe (= 13.2)

    Stripe (~> 19.0.1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `Stripe (~> 19.0.1), Stripe (= 13.2)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

[!] There are duplicate dependencies on `Stripe` in `Podfile`:

- Stripe (~> 19.0.1)
- Stripe (= 13.2)
'pod install' command failed.
```

And I can see that when I build the project, I can see in the 'platforms/ios/PodFile' that two versions of Stripe are called :

```
# Begin Podfile - /Users/corentin/Desktop/CODE/arian-fitness/node_modules/nativescript-stripe/platforms/ios/Podfile
# platform :ios, '10.0'
pod 'Stripe', '~> 19.0.1'

# Begin Podfile - /Users/corentin/Desktop/CODE/arian-fitness/node_modules/nativescript-stripe-sdk/platforms/ios/Podfile
# platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'Stripe', '13.2'
# End Podfile
```

Does any one knows are to deal with this duplication ?

Comment: Can you please put your Podfile inside a triple-backquote (```) code block? SO is trying to interpret the code as markdown.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using a version of the NativeScript Stripe project that uses Stripe 11.3: https://github.com/piotrilski/nativescript-stripe-sdk

The project's README recommends using this version instead, which supports 19.0.1:
https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-stripe

In either case, you must use the same version of the Stripe SDK in your Podfile and project that the Nativescript library you've chosen uses.

Comment: yes but I can't seem to find how to deal with the versions of Stripe as when I run 'tns plugin add nativescript-stripe' and 'tns plugin add nativescript-stripe-sdk', I have the following lines in my package.json file :  "nativescript-stripe": "^6.6.2",     "nativescript-stripe-sdk": "^1.1.4",     "stripe": "^8.67.0". And the Podfile is generated automatically in 'platforms/ios' folder so I can't control what's inside.